# Can we get LinkedIn profile Picture and headline without using LinkedIn API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linkedin-api

Can we get LinkedIn profile Picture and headline without using LinkedIn API?
Here I have seen that we can do this by using LinkedIn API.

But I want to implement it without using OAuth and LinkedIn API and without log in into LinkedIn.

Just want to get profile picture and if possible, basic profile detail using Profile link only.

Any possibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just crawl the linkedin page for specific html element, and get the picture. Note hovewer, that should the element name change in the future, it will break your code. Also, take into consideration the specific linkedin user agreement, as some companies prohibit using automated software to access they websites.

Would you decide to do this, feel free to reuse the [code](https://github.com/PFalkowski/SitesCrawler) I wrote to find a  website title.

Comment: yes correct Piotr.. but is there any other way to do it? because ur suggestion is not full proof..?

Comment: No, that is the easiest way to do this as far as I know, it resembles opening linkedin website, and downloading a picture. Anything other than that will be either more complicated or involve linkedin API imho.

Comment: thanks Piotr for ur suggestion.. what about using LinkedIn Plugin .. is it feasible for development?